# Testing constructor

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit

My constructor sets property with data which loaded from database. 
How can I test if it really load data from db? I want %100 test coverage rate so I need test every piece of my code.

```
<?php
class PreferencesAdapter {

    private $_preferences = NULL;

    public function __construct() {         
                ...
        $this->load();
                ...
    }

    public function load() {
        ...
        $this->_preferences= DataFromDb();
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd mock `load()` in a test method and verify that it gets called once when creating the object.

Answer (score 0):

(In the interest of fast tests, here is a wordy approach you could do.)

Or, put your relevant queries as public methods in a class PreferencesAdapterQueryCollection, and inject it as an optional constructor parameter to PreferencesAdapter. (If the parameter was not sent in, just instantiate the PreferencesAdapterQueryCollection right there.)

In PreferencesAdapterTest, send in a mocked PreferencesAdapterQueryCollection, with expectations and return values on its public, simple query methods.

I like Mockery for this. See the question [Mockery - call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876849/mockery-call-user-func-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-a-valid-callback) for example invocation.